# How to find out: Domain Administrator or Not?

Tags: powershell

I have an account e.g. (MyDomain\User1) which has ONLY an access to a VM that has Windows Server 2008 R2 installed and nothing else.

I have no access at all to the Active Directory (AD) nor the Dmain Controller (DC).

How can I tell if this particular account (MyDomain\User1) is a Domain Administrator or not? Is there any Windows PowerShell command for that?

Thanks you !

Comment: The list of domain admins is held in the domain. If you have no access to the domain, how can use access information that is held in that domain? The whole point of security barriers is to be barriers.

Answer (score 11):

Easy, just check the current user for membership in the domain admins group.

```
$CurrentUser = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$WindowsPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($CurrentUser)

if($WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole("Domain Admins"))
{
    Write-Host "Currently running as a Domain Admin"
}
else
{
   Write-Host "Keep dreaming, you're not a Domain Admin."
}
```